# Why has my rep dropped 100 points in one day and what can I do to fix it or

Tags: support

... at least keep it from dropping even further?

That's it, basically. Why, and what, and how?

Comment: Looking at your profile page I don't see the missing 100 points, which is weird because I do remember your rep was around the 800 mark. I can't say if it was closer to 850 or 900 though. The two meta posts might help explain, I suspect the reason for the loss of rep points is to be found in the second post.

Comment: Anyway have a look at these meta questions and see if they apply to you [What does ‘User removed’ mean? And why did I get a significant chop-down of reputation?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/what-does-user-removed-mean-and-why-did-i-get-a-significant-chop-down-of-repu?rq=1) and [My reputation has dropped 400 points all of a sudden. Can anyone tell me why?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/my-reputation-has-dropped-400-points-all-of-a-sudden-can-anyone-tell-me-why?rq=1)

Comment: and [Did some of my answers recently get deleted?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/did-some-of-my-answers-recently-get-deleted)

Comment: I'm flattered. Also, I'm totally confused now. What meta posts?

Comment: Oh. Got it! Thanks. No, I'm still in the dark about the loss of points, but at least I'm reassured (sort of) that there's going to be no further drop. At least not today. Am I wrong? I don't know who or what those Sockpuppets are, or why they would do what they're rumored to be doing. Whatever it is, they should be ashamed of themselves. Thanks again!

Comment: Well before jumping to conclusions, wait and see what the mods say. They can see things that we mortals cannot.

Comment: Do those things come to them in their sleep? Just curious.

Comment: I voted to delete the post, without knowing it carried a penalty. I might have asked you to reconsider but three users before me had done that, and you retaliated and defended your answer. But please explain to me why a woman who enjoys "mindless social fun", as described by the OP, with no overtones of sexual activity in the slightest, is in your words a: *slut, airhead, bimbo*? Whereas a man is a: *hellrake, fop, rogue*; terms relatively inoffensive, but in actual fact, sometimes wore as a badge of honour.

Comment: (cont'd) The OP himself said: *"Slut, bimbo: both are highly offensive. All these seem like a personal attack rather than focusing on their lapse in thinking"* You were just pushing the boundaries, seeing how far you could go. It was a cheap nasty insult, aimed at women, and I don't see why I, or any woman or man  should ignore that, or not feel offended.

Comment: BTW I interpret the OP's "mindless social fun" as being rather shallow, frivolous pastimes, such as playing online puzzle games, watching youtube videos, posting updates on their social media profile, generally  light-weight genre. Nothing about having loose sexual relations, being fairly stupid, or acting like a cheap sex object.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't see either how a woman mindlessly playing on Facebook should be called a slut or bimbo.

Comment: Here is a link to a meta post about uncalled for or inexplicable deleted comments. [Disappearing comment trails](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/disappearing-comment-trails?rq=1); here is an older post, but in this case the deleted comment was reinstated. But anonymous deletion is, apparently, acceptable and the done thing. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5019/why-was-this-comment-deleted. Which makes me suspect that every deleted comment is archived. Nothing *really* disappears...

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thank you. I read the answer harangue, and the other harangue linked to the answer harangue. It seems that the powers-that-be here are very strongly opposed to the idea that folks can _communicate_ among one another freely, forming cyber-relationships, etc. They keep reminding us peons that all and any communication, discussion, discourse here is _at their discretion_. Looks like maoists is the wrong word: there's a bit of everybody of that ilk in there: Nero, Henry VIII, Louis XI, Stalin, Mussolini, etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That's weird, because the previous one states that, once deleted, comments disappear forever and ever, amen, no one can access them. So, the powers-that-be aren't above plain old lying, either.

Comment: You're being more melodramatic than I am! Nevertheless, it's unsettling. The infamous deleted answer of mine is visible to me because I have 10+k, but deleted comments are not. And if I delete my comment, I want it to be deleted for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Force of habit, I suppose; once an entertainer, always a clown. But the points we've been making between us are all valid a thousand times over.

Comment: Oh, you shouldn't have. That was very kind of you to post that question. I must have searched "sailed on ship" and "went by ship" and " travelled on/by ship" before asking your advice. Actually, the question you have posted is very neat, you can delete the request for "by ship" and substitute it with "travel on ship" (it's still connected with *on foot*, *on horseback*) if you like, but keep the question title. It's 2.28 am here, I'm knackered. Night.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Sweet dreams.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/283147/100) was marked as offensive, which carries a 100 reputation penalty. An [FAQ on spam and offensive flags is available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/89334).

Comment: Oh good to know, I had no idea there was a penalty involved

Comment: To prevent leaping to conclusions, I haven't flagged anything as offensive in months.

Comment: Thank you. So, someone provides a definition and asks for words it might match; I provide the words (anyone who doubts that the words are actually correct can look them up)  and lose a hundred points. Good to know.

Comment: @Ricky - You claim to be ["always courteous, and even tactful..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/283149/58761). Heh. Maybe that's why you you [didn't really get Shakespeare's quote about fools and wise men](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/282939/58761). Lest you think it's just me, other commenters noticed your answer's **poor quality** ("C'mon, none of your nouns is even close to an answer to the request.")

Comment: @medica:People's OPINIONS (on anything, including my choice of nouns) shouldn't serve as sufficient cause to strip 100 points from my rep. That's simply not decent. Apology not accepted.

Comment: Apology? I didn't offer one; I didn't do anything wrong. It appears, however, that *you* did. End of my involvement.

Comment: Really. What was it exactly that I did wrong? Name the crime, if you please.

Comment: @Ricky I think you should read the link waiwai933♦ posted before accusing *one* user of deliberately deleting 100 rep points. You did it unto yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: Don't be such a scaredy-cat. I've read the link. It does not apply. Which, of course, is a matter of opinion. Let me reiterate. A question was posted. I posted my CORRECT answer. Someone decided to take offense. Because there are people in this world to whom taking offense is second nature. Orwell called them the thought police. We'll be censoring Shakespeare, Byron, and Fielding next. Actually, all of English-language literature. You can't open a book in English without running into an offensive word almost right away. Apology not accepted.

Comment: Oh, so now we're downvoting support questions too.

Comment: @Ricky, you need to preface my username with @ if you want me to receive a notification.  I was one who took offence, because the answer was a cheap insult, it is in no way, shape or form *correct* (how presumptuous of you comparing yourself with Shakespeare and Byron), the OP himself was clearly unsatisfied with your answer. I am not offended in the least  by foul language, I am not offended by words, I am offended by those who spout  nonsensical, sexist and chauvinistic views. Your CORRECT answer falls in that category.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If there's another rake out there on this question, I'm sure Ricky is searching for it so he jump on it with both feet.  That shouldn't obscure the fact that he's right.  Offensive posts are those that constitute hate speech and abuse of people, which I take to mean hateful things directed at individuals.   The real problem with the answer is that it's wrong on the facts; the real problem with Ricky's defense of his answer is that it's empty.  I can't blame you for taking offense, but that doesn't make the answer flag-worthy.

Comment: @deadrat I do not have the authority to unilaterally close or delete posts or comments. I was *one* of the users who flagged Ricky's answer, and I don't regret my decision. He had the time to improve on his answer, or explain on his post why it is CORRECT. He didn't. End of.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What have I posted that suggests I think you have such authority?  Or that I think you should regret your decision?  I'm not in the habit of telling people how they should feel.  Ricky certainly had time to improve or properly defend his answer.  He didn't, and that make it a bad answer.  And in some respects, that makes him a bad actor here.  But his post still doesn't qualify under the guidelines as flag-worthy for offense.  Which, of course, is different from it being offensive to people.

Comment: @deadrat I clarified a possible interpretation that a newcomer might arrive at, that the loss of rep points was due to a single flag, that whenever a post is flagged as offensive the poster loses 100 points. He or she does not. According to the link above, six votes are needed before a user is penalised, hence I was not alone in finding Ricky's post questionable in its taste. His was ALSO the second post defacing women as a sex, and that too has been deleted.

Comment: (cont'd) I am 100 per cent certain that if I had posted the answer *nigga* as someone who enjoys mindless social fun, people would have come down on me like a ton of bricks. And riightly so, but somehow when it comes to women, it's different. The answer is not "flag-worthy for offense." Why isn't it? Doesn't it insult women? Isn't it sexist? That is all I want to say on the matter. If you want to continue the discussion on chat, I'm sorry but I don't visit that place. I really dislike the chat room on EL&U.

Comment: @deadrat please note Ricky's observation **Someone decided to take offense**, it would be easy to interpret that as saying a single user found his post offensive, it is and was not true.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What makes you think I want to discuss how many flags it takes for a poster to lose 100 points? Or how many people found Ricky's answers offensive? Or Ricky's defensive observations about the hole he's dug himself into? Instead of being able to engage you on the difference between hate speech and offensive speech and why that's important on ELU, I fear all I've succeeded in doing is annoy you, which is not my intent.  My failure is a disappointment to me -- see the next comment for the reason -- but it is what it is, and I'll respect that you've spoken all you wish on the matter.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are one of several high-rep posters to ELU and the associated meta whose questions and answers I enjoy perusing.  I think you choose interesting matters to discuss in a clear and coherent style, and I learn from what you post.  I'm sorry this particular exchange wasn't more fruitful.